# iPad displaces cursor in textareas

Tags: css, forms, ipad, cursor, textarea

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?  I've been hitting my head on the desk for the last 2 hours, trying to figure out why the cursor gets displaced on the iPad.  Check out my video to see it:

http://tinypic.com/r/20k6338/7

Here is my CSS:

```
#newroar-ipad {

position: fixed;

display: block;

opacity: 0;

left: 5px;
top: 0px;

height: 480px !important;
width: 550px !important;
margin-top: 30px;

pointer-events: none;

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CCCCCC));

z-index: 4;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px #000;

-webkit-transition: -opacity 0.0s ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: .4s;

-webkit-transform: translate(0px, -20px);


}

#newroar-ipad.show {

opacity: 1.0;
pointer-events: auto;
z-index: 4;

-webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 15px);

}

#newroar-ipad-content-header {

margin-top: 10px;

z-index: 4;

width: 548px;
height: 55px;

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EBEBEB), to(#CCC)); 

border: 1px solid #CCC;

}

#newroar-ipad-content {

margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 2px;

background: none;

top: 0;

width: 542px;
height: 400px;

z-index: 4;

}

.newroar-inputfield {

-webkit-appearance: none;

height: 20px !important;
width: 90%;
margin-left: 18px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

background: #FFF;

color: #666;
font-size: 12px;

border-style: none;
padding: 10px;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;

}

.newroar-textarea {

-webkit-appearance: none;

width: 90%;
height: 120px;
margin-left: 18px;
margin-bottom: 10px;

background: #FFF;

color: #666;
font-size: 12px;

border-style: none !important;
border: none !important;

padding: 10px;

-webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
outline: none !important;

}

.newroar-selectfield {

font-size: 14px !important;

height: 30px !important;
width: 300px !important;

margin-left: 18px !important;
margin-top: 25px !important;
margin-bottom: 25px !important;



}
```

You can see I have tried using !important in case it was bringing styling for other form elements in the CSS document, and I tried the -webkit-appearance to see if it would fix it... with no avail.  =(

Thanks for any advice you may have!

Comment: A jsfiddle or simply an HTML snippet in your question would probably help.

Comment: Holy cow, is there some reason that you use so many !important declarations? If there is some edge-case reason for that, then that's fine (maybe you're overriding user-generated styles or something), but if you're not, then please do some research on !important and try to avoid using it. Generally speaking, you should never need to use it, except in very rare circumstances.

Anyhow, without a demo, the only thing I can think of doing there is setting a different line-height for the fields.

Answer (score 1):

can you try using position:absolute , rather than fixed

```
#newroar-ipad {
position: absolute;
/* other style codes */
}
```

Because ios usually move the input box in focus , to just above the keypad. Seems like the position:fixed code is bringing it back to its original position.